# I want to select sales against saleid which contains both sale of items and deals in that id. from relationship table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

select query please
I have 3 tables 1 with Primary key `(SaleID and date time)`
Other 2 are relationship table foreign key `(SaleID,ItemID)` where both are foreign key 
 and foreign key`(SaleID,DealID)` where both are foreign key
I want to select sales against `saleid` which contains both sale of items and deals in that `id`.

```
SaleID | Date
1          22/8/2013  
2          23/8/2013

SaleID | ItemID
1          2  
1          1
2          2 

SaleID | DealID
1          2  
2          5
```

Result Should be

SaleID

```
   1 
   Burger(Item)
   Roll(Item)
   Deal Combo 

   2 
   Roll(Item)
   Deal Combtob
```

Comment: sqlfiddle would be very helpfull

Comment: Ali please format the table structure to make it readable. Use sql fiddle or pipes |.